# How to add method in unmanaged code in a FaceRecognition project

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv, face-recognition

I'm implementing a little FaceRecognition program using Emgu as a wrapper of OpenCV libraries. It seems to work fine, but I need a function that returns all the distances between the image sample and the faces in the database (the [FaceRecognizer.Predict method](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.2.0/document/html/97e31eb5-5fc5-2061-9f7e-745a8ebe14f3.htm) implemented only returns the smallest distance and label).

So I built Emgu from Git, in order to adapt functions in the unmanaged code (cvextern.dll) to my needs.

Here's the original in face_c.cpp

```
void cveFaceRecognizerPredict(cv::face::FaceRecognizer* recognizer, cv::_InputArray* image, int* label, double* dist)
{ 
    int l = -1;
    double d = -1; 
    recognizer->predict(*image, l, d); 
    *label = l; 
    *dist = d; 
}
```

that stores minimum distance and corresponding label in `l` and `d`, thanks to predict.

The method I wrote, following the [summary](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/face/include/opencv2/face.hpp#L307) in opencv face.hpp:

```
void cveFaceRecognizerPredictCollector(cv::face::FaceRecognizer * recognizer, cv::_InputArray * image, std::vector<int>* labels, std::vector<double>* distances)
{
    std::map<int, double> result_map = std::map<int, double>();
    cv::Ptr<cv::face::StandardCollector> collector = cv::face::StandardCollector::create();

    recognizer->predict(*image, collector);

    result_map = collector->getResultsMap();

    for (std::map<int, double>::iterator it = result_map.begin(); it != result_map.end(); ++it) {
        distances->push_back(it->second);
        labels->push_back(it->first);
    }
}
```

And the caller in c#

```
using (Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfInt labels = new Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfInt())
using (Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfDouble distances = new Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfDouble())
using (InputArray iaImage = image.GetInputArray())
{
    FaceInvoke.cveFaceRecognizerPredictCollector(_ptr, iaImage, labels, distances);
}

[DllImport(CvInvoke.ExternLibrary, CallingConvention = CvInvoke.CvCallingConvention)]
internal extern static void cveFaceRecognizerPredictCollector(IntPtr recognizer, IntPtr image, IntPtr labels, IntPtr distances);
```

The application works in real-time, so the function in c# is called continuously. I have only two faces and one label (same person) stored in my database, so the first call returns correctly the only possible label and stores it in `labels`. Keeping the application running, returned labels and the size of `labels` vector keep growing, filled with unregistered labels that I don't know where he takes. It seems to me like the collector in c++ is not well referenced, so that every time the function is called it keeps storing data without releasing the previous ones, overwriting them. But it's only my guess, I'm not very good with c++.

What else could possily be wrong?

Hope you can help

Comment: You might have introduced a [Memory Leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) (or perhaps one already existed). Most likely memory is being allocated in `cveFaceRecognizerPredictCollector()` (or code called from there) and *ownership of that memory is passed back to your code*, where it would be your responsibility to release that memory when it's no longer needed. If there is documentation (or comments in the code) for the functions you're calling, check to see if there is mention of this ownership. Note: I don't know about these particular projects.

Comment: There is no garbage collector in C++ like there is in C#, although there are things like [`std::unique_ptr<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) that can be used to help you manage memory.

Comment: Also, who is clearing `labels` and `distances`? Unrelated, I recommend passing those parameters as references (`&`) rather than pointers (`*`). If you leave them as pointers, then you should verify that they are not `nullptr`, otherwise you'll invoke undefined behavior and anything can happen. This isn't a problem with a reference (as the compile will help enforce this).

Comment: Never mind, I see you're creating a new `labels` and `distances` in .NET right before calling the DLL function. Maybe you just need to trigger the garbage collector manually to force those to clean up? I'm not sure... But usually having to do that is a suboptimal solution.

Comment: This comment: "collector in c++ is not well referenced, so that every time the function is called it keeps storing data without releasing the previous ones, overwriting them." makes me think you may know all this I mentioned above, and you might have discovered a bug.

Comment: Turns out OpenCV already provides a smart pointer class (cv::Ptr - https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d0/de7/structcv_1_1Ptr.html). So, as I understand it, my `collector` should be automatically cleaned up once his scope block has ended, right? I also tried to use Ptr with `result_map` but keeps me returning random labels